# Где здесь предложение с уточняющим обстоятельством?

Tags: синтаксис

1)В третьих, я бы вспомнил о представлениях души примитивным человеком как некоей сущности, обитающей в теле.
2)И все это понимание души было бы не о своей душе, а как говорят и думают о ней все люди.
3) Между тем у меня была душа своя, и я знал о ней с очень далекого времени, почти с детства, когда проливал потихоньку слезы о том, что я вышел на свет не такой, как все.
4) Мало-помалу с годами, с десятками проходящих лет я через это страданье узнавал свое назначение: мало-помалу оказывалось, что быть не как все, а как сам, и есть то самое необходимое, без чего мое существование было бы бессмысленным.
5) И мое страстное желание присоединиться ко всем, быть как все, не может произойти иначе, как через раскрытие в глазах всех себя самого...

Answer (score 6):

В третьем предложении есть обстоятельство времени (знал с каких пор? - с очень далекого времени), а потом уточняется: с каких именно пор? с какого именно времени? - почти с детства.

Answer (score 1):

В третьем предложении уточняющее обстоятельство времени "почти с детства" обособлено